# How can I remove soap and toothbrush holders?

Tags: drywall, glue

What is the safest and least damaging way to remove existing soap and toothbrush holders from drywall? We would like to remove these holders because we do not use them. It seems the previous owner must have glued them to the wall and perhaps this is the proper convention. Is there a way to remove them without damaging the drywall terribly?

Comment: they might be screwed in can we see some pics?

Comment: The usual convention with wall-mounted bathroom accessories is usually that an anchor is installed in the drywall and the accessory is mounted over that and secured with a small screw on the bottom. It is tough to say whether that could be the case on yours without seeing photos.

Comment: How old is the place? What material are they made of? I am remodeling my bathroom and when I removed the soap and toothbrush holders, I found that there had been a hole cut in the drywall and they were plastered in place. They were surrounded with tile on the walls too, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they really are glued to the wall, a heat gun on low might melt the glue enough to get them off. Then heat the remaining glue and scrape it off.